# Swagger Integration in Jakarta EE 8 project

Tags: jakarta-ee, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am developing a web application using Angular 11 frontend and a Jakarta EE 8 backend. My backend consists maily of JAX-RS end points, for which I wish to provide a Swagger 2.0 Documentation.

In another Spring-Boot project, I used Springfox and I am wondering whether there is a counterpart in the Jakarta EE world.
I tried the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But this produces only the swagger.json with no UI. Additionally, i would like to read the texts inside Swagger annotations e.g. @ApiOperation from a properties file, like I did with Spring e.g.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "${users.getAll.value}", notes = "${users.getAll.notes}")
```

Is there a library that can provide those features?

It is worth mentioning: My project use the pure Java/Jakarta EE API and runs on JBoss EAP 7.2.8, so no specific Jersey or RESTeasy implementations

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId> 
    <version>8.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No see my Answer below

Comment: The problem is now old, but would https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta this dependency that got released since, help?

Answer (score 1):

Again my requirements were:

1. A library that generate both the json and ui
2. Reading from properties files
3. Scanning ExceptionMapper classes

It seems no solution with OpenAPI-2.0. So I used the following link to integrate swagger-ui (so only the first requirement are somehow done)
https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/adding-swagger-to-a-javaee-project-javaee-series-2-part-2/

But with OpenAPI-3.0, the Eclipse Microprofile OpenAPI api is worth trying

```
 <!-- 1. OpenAPI API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
    <version>${microprofile-openapi-api-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- 2. Swagger-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.microprofile-ext.openapi-ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${openapi-ui-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However I could not test it my self, as I am working on JBOSS EAP-7.2.9 and the above API is supported starting version 7.3.1 XP 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Adding the swagger-ui dependency may help.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.microprofile-ext.openapi-ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Source:
https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2020/05/08/microprofile-openapi-and-swagger-ui/
https://github.com/microprofile-extensions/openapi-ext/tree/master/openapi-ui

Comment: thanks, but the above dependency is from microprofile for openAPI 3.0. Is there any additional configuration required? for swagger 2.0 and according to this link, a maven plugin is required to download swagger ui https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/adding-swagger-to-a-javaee-project-javaee-series-2-part-2/